# Hide update messages from non-admin users?

Tags: admin, users, cms, updates

Is it possible to hide the update messages for any users other than the main admin?

We use WP as a CMS for clients and it's a bit annoying that a normal user has to read something like:

> WordPress 3.1.3 is available! Please update now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hide Update reminder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hide-update-reminder/) - this hides update messages for all non-admin users

Comment: The actual plugin is very small, so you can copy it in your theme or somewhere else if you don't want to display it as a separate plugin. The core idea is just `remove_action('admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3);`

Comment: Just to note about Jan's suggestion, that removes it for everyone. If you only want to remove it for the non-admins, see how the plugin does that check. Also don't add the code to your theme. Make it an MU plugin if you must, so you keep it if you switch themes.